# How to get value of DataGridTemplateColumn in DataGridCellEditEnding method

Tags: wpf, datagrid, wpf-controls, datagridtemplatecolumn

I have DataGrid and its itemsource is a list of object which is named WeightItemData.

My all columns in data grid are DataGridTextColumn except one that is DataGridTemplateColumn and it is a Combobox.

My problem is that i cannot get the updated combox value inside the DataGridCellEditEnding method.

```
   <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Crew" SortMemberPath="FsmTypes">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding FsmType}"></TextBlock>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding FsmTypes, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" SelectedItem="{Binding FsmType,Mode=TwoWay}"></ComboBox>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>




    private void DataGridCellEditEnding(object sender, DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBlock cmb = e.EditingElement as TextBlock;

        if (e.EditAction == DataGridEditAction.Commit)
        {
            WeightItemData wid = e.Row.DataContext as WeightItemData;
        }
      }
```

Comment: Are you trying to get value from the `WeightItemData` or `TextBlock`?

Comment: I bind SelectedItem of Combobox to the FsmType of WeightItemData so i tried to get value from WeightItemData

Comment: Did you try to cast e.EditingElement` to a `ComboBox`?

Comment: Please see my answer below. I solved my problem as the code in answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solved my problem as below.

```
    private void DataGridCellEditEnding(object sender, DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.EditAction == DataGridEditAction.Commit)
        {
            WeightItemData wid = e.Row.DataContext as WeightItemData;

            if (e.Column.SortMemberPath.Equals("FsmTypes")) {
                FrameworkElement elmtTest = e.Column.GetCellContent(e.Row);
                ComboBox fsmTypeCombo = ApplicationUtility.FindVisualChild<ComboBox>(elmtTest);
                if(fsmTypeCombo!=null)
                {
                    wid.FsmType = fsmTypeCombo.SelectedValue.ToString();
                    
                }
            }
         }
      }

  public static T FindVisualChild<T>(DependencyObject obj) where T : DependencyObject
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(obj); i++)
        {
            DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(obj, i);
            if (child != null && child is T)
                return (T)child;
            else
            {
                T childOfChild = FindVisualChild<T>(child);
                if (childOfChild != null)
                    return childOfChild;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```